# Why is an Await Delay Ending at End of Function Scope

Tags: javascript, async-await

## Background

I am exploring Async/Await syntax, and I thought I had a clever way of waiting on CSS transitions built. It's not working, though, and I can't figure out why.

## Code

```
const setStyleAndWait = async function( el, property, value ) {

    var setTheStyle = (el, property, value) =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
            el.style[property] = value;
            const transitionEnded = e => {
                if (e.propertyName !== property) return;
                el.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnded);
                resolve();
            }
            el.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnded);
        });

    await setTheStyle( this, property, value );

    console.log('Run logic inside await\'s parent scope');

};

setStyleAndWait( element, 'opacity', '0' ); // element is a reference to an element with a transition on for it's opacity style
console.log('Run logic outside await\'s parent scope.)
```

## Question

When I run this, the outer console.log runs immediately, while the inner waits until the promise is resolved. Why is the outer logic not waiting for the function to finish?

Comment: You need to use `await setStyleAndWait(...)`

Comment: @Barmar is right, unless this is the outer-most scope.  If it is, (and since [we don't have top level await yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)) just do `setStyleAndWait(...).then(() => console.log("Run..."));`

Comment: An async function will terminate at first `await` and create a *continuation* - a code that is put into the event loop when the promise is fulfilled. Only then the remaining code executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setStyleAndWait` function is asynchronous and not being awaited, so it returns immediately leading to that outer log finishing first. You can rewrite that as :
`setStyleAndWait(element, 'opacity', '0').then(() => console.log('this runs after completion'))`

or wrap the entire thing in an async function so you can use `await`.

Answer (score 1):

why should it wait, when you declare a function with the async keyword, what you are saying is that your function is returning a promise. if you want the function caller to wait for the function to resolve/reject you have to use await or then/catch as you want.

In your code, you just have to add await to setStyleAndWait()

Answer (score 1):

When you add async in front of a function, you are making that function asynchronous, it means that the function is executed but the code jumps to next line not waiting for the resolution.

So in order to make this work you need to encapsulate the entire code inside an async function, and make the constant setStyleAndWait to wait for a value to continue with an await

```
 async function envelope(){
     const setStyleAndWait = await function(//rest of code)
 }
```